# good examples of testing ember with rest adapter in quint or mocha

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js, qunit

I have been trying to test my ember application for 2 days with no success. There are examples out there that use fixtures but I was wondering if you might have an example of test scripts where RESTAdapter was used. I have tried using Fixtures for testing as you can see in the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/deewen/u68Mx/1/, but that is also not working for me(sorry I couldn't find proper expect.js file).

```
it("Check analyticsRuns controller", function () {
    //var controller = AS.__container__.lookup('controller:analyticsRunsIndex');
    //the returns null too even though I have that controller
    visit('/analytics')
        .then(function() {
            expect(find('*')).to.not.be(undefined);

    });
});
```

Any suggestions for resource or read that could guide me on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't want your test to hit a live API endpoint because at that point you're not only testing your application code, you're also testing both the functionality of the API and the state of any data that may (or may not) already be stored in the API service.

The Ember Data tests setup fake AJAX responses, much like you'd do with something like webmock on the server side.  Something like that is probably the way to go.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/adapter/rest_adapter_test.js#L34-L55